# How to get the list with all positions of elements matching the given combinations?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, table

Consider the table

```
Table1 = {1,1,-1,0,0,0};
```

How can the list `combinations` be obtained with positions of all non-repeating pairs of elements for which the values are either {1, -1}, or {0,0}? I.e.,

```
combinations={{1,3},{2,3},{4,5},{4,6},{5,6}}
```

In general, `Table1` may consist of both even and odd numbers of elements.

This is my attempt:

```
PairCombinations = {{}};
PairCombinationsTemp[i_, j_] := 
 If[Table1[[i]] + Table1[[j]] == 
   0, {{i, j}}, {{}}]
Do[PairCombinations = 
  Join[PairCombinations, PairCombinationsTemp[i, j]], {i, 1, 
  Length[Table1]}, {j, i + 1, 
  Length[Table1]}]
Select[PairCombinations, UnsameQ[#, {}] &]
```

But it seems to me that it is not well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Table1 = {1,1,-1,0,0,0};

SequencePosition[Table1, {1, ___, -1} | {0, ___, 0}, 
  Overlaps -> All] // SortBy[Last]
```

> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}}

Answer (score 7):

```
Select[Total @ Table1[[#]] == 0 &] @ Subsets[Range @ Length @ Table1, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}}
> ```

```
Select[MatchQ[{1, -1} | {0, 0}] @ Table1[[#]] &] @
 Subsets[Range @ Length @ Table1, {2}]  (* thanks: @IAmANaif *)
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}}
> ```

Comment: Your command structure and the actual specified test: `Select[Subsets[Range[Length[Table1]], {2}], MemberQ[{{1, -1}, {0, 0}}, Table1[[#1]]] & ]`.

Answer (score 6):

```
SubsetPosition[{1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, -1} | {0, 0}]
```

> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}}

Answer (score 5):

According to @kglr and @Anon's answers, another variant to doing this using `GroupBy` and `Extract` is as follows:

```
l1 = {1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0};

Extract[GroupBy[Subsets[Range@Length@l1, {2}],MatchQ[{1, -1}|{0, 0}]@l1[[#]] &],Key[True]]

(*{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}}*)
```

According to @Syed's answer, a little variant is as follows:

```
Catenate@(SubsetPosition[l1, #] & /@ {{1, -1}, {0, 0}})

(*{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}}*)
```